# How/Why does Google Pass (not fail) SPF when the sending domain/IP are not in my SPF record

Tags: gmail, sendgrid, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have looked through other answers here but they all talk about the negative (not passing)
I have a situation where I would expect it to fail on Gmail but it does not.

I am using an e-commerce platform "Sharetribe"
they use "sendgrid" (Twilio) to send customer communications.
I have set up 3 DNS records for sendgrid, all are CNAMEs, 2 look to be DKIM keys and another one similar.

```
12345678.u1234.sendgrid.net
flx.domainkey.12345678.u1234.sendgrid.net
flx2.domainkey.12345678.u1234.sendgrid.net
```

But no SPF record has been setup for this 3rd party platform yet, as they do not offer it, which is why I started to question the spf?
Maybe the standards and protocols have changed???

for example this is my SPF record:

**"v=spf1 include:our.email.service ~all"**

...it does not include Saretribe or sendgrid.

**so why would google pass the SPF?**

This is a similar example to what is in my customer's received Gmail email HEADER:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@our.domain header.s=flx header.b="dca/fgbb";
   dkim=pass header.i=@sendgrid.info header.s=smtpapi header.b=dfgdfg;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+34564567-456- recipient=gmail.com@em404.our.domain designates 168.245.24.68 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+34564567-456-recipient=gmail.com@em404.our.domain"
Return-Path: <bounces+34564567-456-recipient=gmail.com@em404.our.domain>
[![enter image description here][1]][1]Received: from o1.flex-mail.sharetribe.com (o1.flex-mail.sharetribe.com. [168.245.24.68])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id bx41-sdgfhbsrgberthberhbreybtyrbtyjbtyjbtyjb.111.2023.10.31.15.06.27
    for <recipient@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Tue, 31 Oct 2023 15:06:28 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces+34564567-456-recipient=gmail.com@em404.our.domain designates 168.245.24.68 as permitted sender) client-ip=168.245.24.68;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@our.domain header.s=flx header.b="dca/fgbb";
   dkim=pass header.i=@sendgrid.info header.s=smtpapi header.b=dfgdfg;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+34564567-456-recipient=gmail.com@em404.our.domain designates 168.245.24.68 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+34564567-456-recipient=gmail.com@em404.our.domain"
```

[image]

Comment: The only thought I have is maybe google passes the SPF because the DKIM is a pass.
but I cannot find any information that would support this theory.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a response from Sharetribe...

The CNAME record named em404.our.domain with a value of 12345678.u1234.sendgrid.net

**points to another SPF record setup at 12345678.u1234.sendgrid.net**

and our spf record at our.domain is not needed for emails sent from sendgrid and spf should work perfectly everywhere.

So the above picture should have had a green tick when using em404 sub domain.